# Marking some lines of an algorithm with an asterisk, why it doesn't always work?

Tags: algorithm2e, pseudocode

I'm working with IEEEtran and algorithm2e package. I have an algorithm with numbered lines. I am marking some lines with an asterisk before the line as follows:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

% *** MATH PACKAGES ***
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}

\nlset{1}$x=1$\;
\nlset{*2}\For{$i=1$ \emph{\KwTo} $10$}{
\nlset{*3}$x=x+1$\;
\nlset{*4}}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that I cannot produce an asterisk in the line "end" of the for loop: Instead, the code above generates a new line before the "end" line and marks it with the asterisk. 
Is there a way out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\SetNlSty{}{}{}` instead and put it in a group with the lines you want to add a star to.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
$x=1$\;
{% star group begin 
    \SetNlSty{textbf}{*}{}
    \For{$i=1$ \emph{\KwTo} $10$}{
    $x=x+1$\;
    }
}% star group end
$x=2$
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: algorithm2e]

Comment: How can I customize only the "end" line number? Let's say changing it's number for the "a" letter.